# Close drawer when navigating on parent router

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I currently have a StackNavigator as top router with route "Menu", "Settings". The Menu route is a DrawerNavigator with routes such as "home", "articles", etc.

Being on route Home, If if I open the side menu and navigate to "Settings" the side menu is not closed automatically but I'm correctly navigated to Settings. I tried to dispatch a Navigate action with subAction that close drawer ('DrawerClose') but that does not close the side menu. I cannot either close the sidemenu and then redirect to settings as I don't know when the side menu is closed (with the available api).

This behavior is I guess pretty common (for example gmail works like this) and I don't find any easy way to do this.